# logarithm base b in prolog

Tags: prolog, logarithm

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
logbN(1,_,0).
logbN(N,B,Ans):-
    N1 = N/B,
    logbN(N1, B, A),
    A is Ans + 1.
```

This is supposed to calculate log_b N and store the result in Ans I keep getting out of local stack error

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out for anyone else that needs to know how to do this.

```
logbN(1,_,0).
logbN(N,B,Ans):-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N/B,
    logbN(N1, B, A),
    Ans is A + 1.
```

I had 'A' and 'Ans' mixed up

Comment: Looks like you also replaced `=/2` (incorrect) with `is/2` (correct).